# Does filter2D in opencv really do its job?

Tags: python, opencv, correlation, convolution

I am doing something about convolving images in Python and for sake of speed I chose opencv 2.4.9.

Opencv offers a way called *filter2D* to do this and here's its docs: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2d

In docs, it says:

> Convolves an image with the kernel.

But I have doubts(caused by something else) so I make some experiments on it:

First, I make a normal 3x3 matrix *a* using numpy as:

> ```
>   [[ 1.,  5.,  0.], 
>    [ 7.,  2.,  9.], 
>    [ 2.,  3.,  4.]]
> ```

Then, I make a 2x2 matrix *b* as the kernel as:

> >>> b
>
> ```
>   [[ 1.,  2.],
>    [ 3.,  4.]]
> ```

Finally, in order to make it clear to see difference between **convolve** and **correlate**, rotate *b* by 180 degree and *b* will look like:

> ```
>   [[ 4.,  3.],
>    [ 2.,  1.]]
> ```

Now, All pre-work is done. We could begin the experiment.

Step 1. Use *scipy.ndimage.convolve*: `ndconv = ndimage.convolve(a, b, mode = 'constant')` and *ndconv* is:

> ```
>   [[ 35.,  33.,  18.],
>    [ 41.,  45.,  44.],
>    [ 17.,  24.,  16.]]
> ```

**Convolution op** will rotate *b* by 180 degree and do **correlation** using *b* on *a*. So ndconv[0][0] = 4*1+3*5+2*7+1*2 = 35, and ndconv[2][2] = 4*4+3*0+2*0+1*0 = 16

This result is **correct**.

Step 2. Use *scipy.ndimage.correlate*: `ndcorr = ndimage.correlate(a, b, mode = 'constant')` and *ndcorr* is:

> ```
>   [[  4.,  23.,  15.],
>    [ 30.,  40.,  47.],
>    [ 22.,  29.,  45.]]
> ```

According to **correlation**'s definition, *ndcorr[0][0]* = 1*0+2*0+3*0+4*1 = 4 because the border will expand by **0**.

(Someone may be confused by the expandation's difference between conv and corr.
It seems *convolve* expand image in directions **right and down** while *correlate* in directions **left and up**.)

But this is not the point.

Step 3. Use *cv2.filter2D*: `cvfilter = cv2.filter2D(a, -1, b)` and *cvfilter* is:

> ```
>   [[ 35.,  34.,  35.],
>    [ 41.,  40.,  47.],
>    [ 33.,  29.,  45.]]
> ```

If we ignore the border cases, we will find that what *cv2.filter2D* did is actually a **correlation** other than a **convolution**! How could I say that?

> because **cvfilter[1..2][1..2] == ndcorr[1..2][1..2]**.

WEIRD, isn't it?

Could anyone be able to tell the real thing that *cv2.filter2D* do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read a bit further down in the description in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d):

> The function does actually compute correlation, not the convolution:
>
> [image: OpenCV filter2d() formula]
>
> That is, the kernel is not mirrored around the anchor point. If you need a real convolution, flip the kernel using `flip()` and set the new anchor to `(kernel.cols - anchor.x - 1, kernel.rows - anchor.y - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think that's true for OpenCV. If you want real convolution according to Digital Image Processing theory, you should manually reverse the kernel prior to applying `cv2.filter2D`.

Comment: Thanks. So it is a mistake or it's designed to be so?

Comment: @Lancelod I don't think this is so severe to be a mistake. Just as the definition of convolution is ambiguous in different communities. This in my opinion is very common for something could be exited in different communities, isn't it? Also you can see the world-stunning Convolutional-Neural-Network has not claimed a reversed kernel when using convolve for network training. Thus, I propose this could be regarded as a different definition held by different people.